# Python nested error handling

Tags: python, nested, try-catch

I want to ignore some exception in an library code (not my code)
as so:

```
try:
    try: # not my code start
        assert False
    except:
        print('not my code') # not my code end
except:
    print('my code')
    pass
```

So I will get into printing 'my code' at the end.
The results currently is:
'not my code' only.

Comment: The library already handled the exception, you can't prevent that.

Comment: You could rewrite this specific function/method you call from this lib in your code if you don't want to/can't patch the lib. Or find a way to tell if the exception was raised, other than exception handling, which obviously can be tricky if even possible,

Answer (score 0):

You will get *my code* if the inner block, *as a whole* raises an exception. In your case, the inner block

```
try: # not my code start
    assert False
except:
    print('not my code') # not my code end
```

has handled it's exception, so, from the point of view of the outer `try`, it has completed successfully.

You could only cause the outer exception to be triggered by, raising an unhandled exception in the first `try`, or calling a function that raises an exception.

Comment: So there is no solution to ignore exceptions ?

Comment: If you use `try`, you have to use `except`. If you want to ignore the exception, just don't use `try-except`. Just do `assert False` in the inner block.

Comment: If the code you don't have access to catches its own exception, there's nothing you can do